# Print 4 numbers (that are divisible by 3 and 6) before x and store them in an array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, numbers

I wanted to print 4 numbers (that is divisible by 3 and 6) before x and store it in an array. For example, if I input `29` the code will print `6 12 18 24`.

My code so far which doesn't even work:

```java
int array[] = new int[4];
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
int x = sc.nextInt();
for (int counter = 1; counter <= x; counter++) {
    if (counter % 3 == 0 && counter % 6 == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = counter;
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't explain why it doesn't work. Cannot compile? Does it fail? what's the output?

Comment: the output shows incorrectly it just prints
6
6
6
6
12
12
12
12
18
18
18
18
24
24
24
24

Comment: Its printing 4 times because of the array loop , everytime a divisible number is found it prints it 4 times , Check the answer I have posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were 2 problems. First you were adding extra unnecessary loop when your condition was true for division check and second you were starting your loop from `1` to `x` while your expected output is to check the divisibility from `x` to `1`. Here's the fix:

```java
int array[] = new int[4];
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
int x = sc.nextInt(), i = 0;
System.out.println(x);
for (int counter = x - 1; counter > 0; counter--) {
    if (counter % 3 == 0 && counter % 6 == 0) {
        array[i] = counter;
        System.out.println(array[i]);
        i++;
        if (i == 4) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Check: https://ideone.com/5HYhsT

Comment: thanks! i have another question, if i wanted to print 4 numbers after x instead, what should be changed?

Comment: Start counter from x to infinity and check i.e., for(int counter=x+1; ; counter++)

Comment: Notice that there is not stopping condition in for loop that means its an infinite loop. It will stop when i is 4 i.e., when 4 elements are found

Answer (score 1):

```java
int array[] = new int[4];
int index = 0;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
int x = sc.nextInt();
for (int counter = x; counter >= 0; counter--) {
    if (counter % 3 == 0 && counter % 6 == 0 && index < 4) {
        array[index] = counter;
        System.out.println(array[index]);
        index++;
    }
}
```

Your array loop is overriding the value every time a number divisible by 3 or 6 is found

```
Enter a number: 29
6
12
18
24
```

Answer (score 0):

If a number is divisible by 6, then it is also divisible by 3 (because 6 is divisible by 3). The second condition can be omitted:

```java
int number = 29;
int[] arr = IntStream
        // iteration backwards from 'number' to 0
        .iterate(number, i -> i > 0, i -> i - 1)
        // elements that are divisible
        // by 6 without remainder
        .filter(i -> i % 6 == 0)
        // first 4 elements
        .limit(4)
        .toArray();
```

```java
// output
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
// [24, 18, 12, 6]
```